# MicroStrategy Library api fails due to missing idToken

Tags: microstrategy

I'm getting an error `Error when restoring the idToken` while trying to access {{domain}}/MicroStrategyLibrary/api/model/tables/xxxxxxxx

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "8004cb07",
            "message": "Error when restoring the idToken: For input string: \"\"",
            "moreInfo": "https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/KB484255-Configure-the-Modeling-Service",
            "additionalProperties": {
                "arguments": [
                    "For input string: \"\""
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The docs says:

> Make sure the "modelservice.identity_token.secret_key" in the
> modelservice.conf file is configured correctly. It should be the same
> as "identityToken.secretKey" in the Library server
> configOverride.properties file.

Then I've navigated into the file `modelservice.conf` which is located in `...\MicroStrategy\ModelingService\admin`.
And I see the `modelservice.identity_token.secret_key=xxxxxxx` so the file has the property set, as well as the `configOverride.properties` value inside the `configOverride.properties` file.

**What Am I missing here? in order to make it recognize the idToken**

Here is the full error inside the ModelService logs:

> [2024-01-24T09:43:48Z][ERROR][MicroStrategy-F][P3640T1034][com.microstrategy.modelservice.actionhandler.ErrorHandler]
> {"errors":[{"code":"8004cb07","message":"Error when restoring the
> idToken: For input string:
> ""","moreInfo":"https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/KB484255-Configure-the-Modeling-Service","additionalProperties":{"arguments":["For
> input string: """]}}]}
> com.microstrategy.modelservice.gateway.exception.MstrGatewayException:
> Error when restoring the idToken: For input string: ""    at
> com.microstrategy.modelservice.gateway.request.MstrServerSessionBuilder.restoreSessionStateFromIdToken(MstrServerSessionBuilder.java:255)
> ~[com.microstrategy.m2021_2309.modelservice-gateway-11.3.1160.01163.jar:11.3.1160.01163]
> at
> com.microstrategy.modelservice.gateway.request.MstrServerSessionBuilder.restoreSessionStateFromIdTokenRetry(MstrServerSessionBuilder.java:269)
> ~[com.microstrategy.m2021_2309.modelservice-gateway-11.3.1160.01163.jar:11.3.1160.01163]
> at
> com.microstrategy.modelservice.instancemanager.ModelInstanceManager.getSessionState(ModelInstanceManager.scala:174)
> ~[com.microstrategy.m2021_2309.modelservice-11.3.1160.01163-sans-externalized.jar:?]
> at
> com.microstrategy.modelservice.instancemanager.ModelInstanceManager.newInstance(ModelInstanceManager.scala:83)
> ~[com.microstrategy.m2021_2309.modelservice-11.3.1160.01163-sans-externalized.jar:?]
> at
> com.microstrategy.modelservice.request.ActionRequestBase.validateInstanceId(ActionRequestBase.java:79)
> ~[com.microstrategy.m2021_2309.modelservice-11.3.1160.01163-sans-externalized.jar:?]
> at
> com.microstrategy.modelservice.request.command.InstanceCommandBase.validate(InstanceCommandBase.java:17)
> ~[com.microstrategy.m2021_2309.modelservice-11.3.1160.01163-sans-externalized.jar:?]
> at
> com.microstrategy.modelservice.request.command.GetTableCommand.validate(GetTableCommand.java:32)
> ~[com.microstrategy.m2021_2309.modelservice-11.3.1160.01163-sans-externalized.jar:?]
> at
> com.microstrategy.modelservice.actionhandler.ActionHandlerBase.init(ActionHandlerBase.scala:23)
> ~[com.microstrategy.m2021_2309.modelservice-11.3.1160.01163-sans-externalized.jar:?]
> at
> com.microstrategy.modelservice.actionhandler.ActionHandlerFactory$.handle(ActionHandlerFactory.scala:29)
> ~[com.microstrategy.m2021_2309.modelservice-11.3.1160.01163-sans-externalized.jar:?]
> at
> com.microstrategy.modelservice.controller.ModelServiceAction.handle(ModelServiceAction.scala:88)
> ~[com.microstrategy.m2021_2309.modelservice-11.3.1160.01163-sans-externalized.jar:?]
> at
> com.microstrategy.modelservice.controller.ModelServiceAction.$anonfun$handle$1(ModelServiceAction.scala:70)
> ~[com.microstrategy.m2021_2309.modelservice-11.3.1160.01163-sans-externalized.jar:?]
> at scala.Function1.$anonfun$andThen$1(Function1.scala:87)
> ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.13.9.jar:?]  at
> play.api.mvc.ActionBuilderImpl.invokeBlock(Action.scala:441)
> ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.13-2.8.16.jar:2.8.16]  at
> play.api.mvc.ActionBuilderImpl.invokeBlock(Action.scala:439)
> ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.13-2.8.16.jar:2.8.16]  at
> play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$8.invokeBlock(Action.scala:289)
> ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.13-2.8.16.jar:2.8.16]  at
> play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$8.invokeBlock(Action.scala:284)
> ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.13-2.8.16.jar:2.8.16]  at
> play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$9.apply(Action.scala:379)
> ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.13-2.8.16.jar:2.8.16]  at
> play.api.mvc.Action.$anonfun$apply$4(Action.scala:82)
> ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.13-2.8.16.jar:2.8.16]  at
> scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.run(Promise.scala:470)
> ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.13.9.jar:?]  at
> akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
> ~[com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.13-2.6.19.jar:2.6.19]    at
> akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)
> ~[com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.13-2.6.19.jar:2.6.19]    at
> scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
> ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.13.9.jar:?]  at
> scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:94)
> ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.13.9.jar:?]  at
> akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)
> ~[com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.13-2.6.19.jar:2.6.19]    at
> akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:49)
> ~[com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.13-2.6.19.jar:2.6.19]    at
> akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:48)
> ~[com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.13-2.6.19.jar:2.6.19]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) ~[?:?]
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
> ~[?:?]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) ~[?:?]
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
> ~[?:?]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
> ~[?:?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, looks like the token has exprired, still didn't invesitigate how to re-new it, but re-installing the Micro (with repair) did the job.